# ZeroMQ for arm_v5t_le using Montavista Pro 5.0 Toolchain

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, embedded-linux, zeromq

Unfortunately I'm not a linux expert. I tried 0MQ (ZeroMQ) communcation library on my host computer and want to use it for an embedded device. The CPU is an TI DM64x (arm_v5t_le architecture), we use Montavista Pro 5.0 Toolchain.

I see the ZeroMQ is based in the Autotools. My question is, does anybody know how easy or how complicated it is to use the cross tools to build the ZeroMQ library? Please don't forget, I don't know the philosophy of Autotools.

Thanks,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to cross-compile an autotooled package is to provide an alternate `host` parameter:

```
./configure --host=i586-pc-mingw32msvc
```

Would, for example, cross-compile for Win32. When `configure` checks for a compiler and `host` is set, it will try to find a compiler with a name like `i586-pc-mingw32msvc-gcc`. What's the name of your cross compiler's executable?

Answer (score 0):

The name is arm_v5t_le-gcc. I guess the installation procedure for MontaVista doesn't place the package in a place where it can be found by the Autotools.

I tried this script, seems to work. Is there a better way?

```
#! /bin/sh
CC=/opt/montavista/pro/devkit/arm/v5t_le/bin/arm_v5t_le-gcc \
RANLIB=/opt/montavista/pro/devkit/arm/v5t_le/bin/arm_v5t_le-ranlib \
STRIP=/opt/montavista/pro/devkit/arm/v5t_le/bin/arm_v5t_le-strip \
./configure \
--host=arm-linux \
--prefix=/tmp/az
```